# How can I add links to an android menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an android app. I'm currently using the WebView. How would I go about creating Internet links from the popup menu (3 dots on the top right)? And how would I open them within the WebView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `OptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Your Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/link1"
        android:title="@string/link1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/link2"
        android:title="@string/link2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

Create an `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case android.R.id.link1:
                // load up WebView with the link
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Your WebView:

```
WebView myWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
myWebView.loadUrl("yourLink");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

but then don't forget to create a WebViewClient:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm new to android app development. i kinda got lost after i created the menu items. how do i go about: "Create an onOptionsItemSelected:"

Comment: just copy and paste this in your Activity or Fragment

Comment: Did you extend Activity in your class? Or is it a fragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125888/trying-to-create-menu-item-links-on-android

Comment: please check that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125888/trying-to-create-menu-item-links-on-android