# Trying to create menu item links on android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't get it to link to webpages. "Reset" and "About" should do. Using webview. Need for the links to open within the webview.

here's the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.test.apppackage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebview ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    setContentView(mWebview );



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.menu_reset:
            mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk");
            setContentView(mWebview );
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }

   }
}
```

here's the activity main.xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_reset"
    android:title="@string/menu_reset"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_about"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    /></menu>
```

here's the strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">App name</string>
<string name="menu_reset">Reset</string>
<string name="menu_about">About app</string>
```

Comment: if you handle the optionitemselected, you should return true. I don't see why you override the shouldoverrideurlloading. you don't need to call setcontentview again, loadUrl should be sufficient.

Comment: receiving errors here: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

Comment: define "receiving errors"

Comment: and here: case android.R.id.menu_reset:

Comment: eclipse is telling me that there's errors with the coding on those two lines.

Comment: MenuItem cannot be resolved to a type                         menu_reset cannot be resolvede or is not a field

Comment: MenuItem cannot be resolved because you are not, like, importing it

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing android.R and R

Your items are called `@+id/menu_reset`, which is created in your `com.test.apppackage.R.java` file.

But you are later comparing to `android.R.id.menu_reset`, which would be in android.R.id, but doesn't exist.

You need to use only your R.java in this case. Use `com.test.apppackage.R.id.menu_reset`.

In some cases, you can use android values, but anyway mixing won't work.

### edit

apparently, android.R.menu_reset doesn't even exist

### more edit

R is actually R.id, of course

Comment: so how would i fix that. i want to use @+id/menu_reset in my package: com.test.apppackage.R.java

Comment: sorry, i'm a complete novice at android and eclipse. what should i replaced android.R.menu_reset with?

Comment: Use com.test.apppackage.R.menu_reset.

Comment: com.test.apppackage.R.menu_reset still producing errors: com.test.apppackage.R.menu_reset cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: my @+id/menu_reset is created in my strings.xml btw

Comment: no. in strings.xml, you create R.string.menu_reset. Try cleaning you project

Comment: sorry but its created in activity_main.xml. see above my original code ^

Comment: Error: String types not allowed (at 'id' with value 'R.string.menu_reset').

Comment: sorry for the typo, R is actually R.id. Your item is R.id.menu_reset (the R from your package, not from android, that is)

Comment: yes, fixed that bit. but still receiving error here:   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

Comment: (thanks for the previous fix). just one more to go:   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

Comment: what error do you have ? (tried ctrl+shift+o ?(or right click 'fix imports' ?))

Comment: please see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126423/trying-to-add-a-second-link-to-app-menu-android

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type Duplicate method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) in type MainActivity MainActivity.java line 47 Java Problem