# trying to add a second link to app menu android

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to add a second link to the menu. the first one has worked fine. the second is called `menu_about`

```
package com.test.apppackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_reset:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.google.com/news");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }
   }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_about:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }
   }


}
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type Duplicate method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) in type MainActivity MainActivity.java line 47 Java Problem

Comment: This code won't compile because you've duplicated your method and your internal class. You need to add the case from the second onOptionsItemSelected method to the switch statement in the first. I suggest you read up on switch statements and perhaps Java in general.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // <-- this
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_reset:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.google.com/news");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }
   }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // <-- and this
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_about:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Delete one of them and switch the id like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_reset:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.google.com/news");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;
            case com.homeovitality.productrecommender.R.id.menu_about:
                mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk");
                setContentView(mWebview );
                break;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```